# Custom hook gitlab. Git can't connect use ssh to a remote server

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I created a `post-receive` hook

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -tt server@ip && cd test_site  && git pull origin master
```

I can't add the id.pub server for git. I tried using `sudo -u git ssh-copy-id -i ~ / .ssh / id_rsa.pub server@ip`, but it gives an error:

> /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': Permission denied

I was trying to add server `id_rsa.pub` in `/var/opt/gitlab/authorized_keys`. But this don't work and when I execute the script produces an error:

> Counting objects: 3, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (3/3),
>   343 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   remote: Permission denied, please try again. remote: Permission
>   denied, please try again. remote: Permission denied
>   (publickey,password). To
>   http://testgitlab.com/root/project11.git    d48fc3c..eb596e7 
>   master -> master

Comment: does this work? `sudo -u git -i ~git/.ssh/id_rsa.pub server-test@ip`

Comment: also the post receive hook should be as `ssh -tt server@ip 'cd test_site && git pull origin master'`. Otherwise you run the `cd` and `git pull` commands locally

Comment: -sh: 1: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied

Comment: and did you check the permissions on the file and its container directories? are they readable by the git user? `ls -ld ~git ~git/.ssh ~git/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 dec 12 01:27 /var/opt/gitlab
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 dec 14 14:46 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git   392 dec 14 13:22 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: well, if all else fails, just take the contents of `/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy it to `~server/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `ip` manually

Comment: It works. Thank you. I realized my mistake

Comment: On the test server, everything works. i'm try to do same thing to the work server who connect to the hosting server. 'git push origin master 
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 252 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Connection to IP closed.
To http://git.server.com/name/project11.git
   59252f5..5140a88  master -> master'                                               If i'm execute script manualy it's want password

Comment: If i'm connect use sudo -u git it's connect without password. Owner post-receive hook git:git and he  executable